# Spring data Specification with entity relations

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, hibernate, specifications

i have this entity:

```
@Data
@Builder
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Entity
public class Employee implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "EMPLOYEE_ID")
    private Long employeeId;

   @Column(name = "FK_OTHER_ENTITY")
    private Long otherEntityId;

.......

}
```

and entity 2:

```
 @Data
    @Builder
    @AllArgsConstructor
    @NoArgsConstructor
    @Entity
    public class OtherEntity implements Serializable {
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    
        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
        @Column(name = "OTHER_ID")
        private Long otherEntityId;
    
       @Column(name = "DATE_FIRST")
        private Date dateFirst;

        @Column(name = "DATE_LAST")
        private Date dateLast;
    
    .......
    
    }
```

I want to create a specification of first entity but i have this sql:

```
select a.* from employee a, other entity b where a.FK_OTHER_ENTITY = b.OTHER_ID AND "DATE1 OF INPUT" >= b.DATE_FIRST and "DATE2 of INPUT" <= b.DATE_LAST
```

How i access to an attribute of other entity that has a simple foreign key and not a relationship?

Thank you for the response

Answer (score 0):

You can use ad hoc joins from Hibernate 5.1:

[How to join unrelated entities with JPA and Hibernate](https://thorben-janssen.com/how-to-join-unrelated-entities/)

[Hibernate docs: Explicit joins](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.4/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#hql-explicit-join)

Just use
`inner join` or `left join` with `on` clause.

You can use ordinary SQL joins, if you are going to use SQL (not JPQL).

Comment: So i dont use Specification? @v.ladynev

Comment: @Alex Sorry. I didn't get that the question is about `specifications`. Your `where` clause is always the same (the two dates comparison), so much better to use `JPQL` here.

Comment: @Alex if the and entity has a ManyToOne relation, can i create an Expression for example Expression<List<EntityRelation>> userExpression = root.<EntityRelation>>

Comment: @Alex I haven't got. I will delete my answer.